# While-loop not breaking when extra 'int' keyword added?

Tags: c

I was doing some exercises on codewars, and had to make a digital_root function (recursively add all digits of a number together, up untill there's only one digit left). 
I was fairly confident that I did it right, but for some reason my while-loop never broke, even though my prints showed that len was 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int digital_root(int n) {
  char number[10];
  sprintf(number, "%d", n);

  int len = strlen(number);
  printf("Outer print: %s %d %d\n", number, n, len);
  int sum = 0;
  while(len > 1)
  {
    sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
    {
      sum += number[i] - '0';
    }
    sprintf(number, "%d", sum);
    int len = strlen(getal);       //!!!
    printf("Inner print: %s %d %d\n", number, sum, len);


  }

  return sum;

}
```

It took me a long time to figure out what was wrong. I noticed that I copy pasted the 'int' keyword when I recalculated the len in the while loop (line marked with !!!). When I removed that (because it was not needed to redefine it as an int, it already was), everything suddenly worked like it was supposed to.

This kinda confused me. Why would this matter? I understand that redefining it is bad practice, but I don't get how this would result in the while-loop not breaking?

The used compiler is Clan3.6/C11.

(Ps. When I tried the same code in TIO, it worked in both cases...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not redefining an existing variable, you're defining a new variable.

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 42;
    printf("Outside, start.     x (%p) = %d\n", (void *)&x, x);
    {
        printf("Inner block, start. x (%p) = %d\n", (void *)&x, x);
        int x = 123;
        printf("Inner block, end.   x (%p) = %d\n", (void *)&x, x);
    }
    printf("Outside, end.       x (%p) = %d\n", (void *)&x, x);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Outside, start.     x (0x7ffd6e6b8abc) = 42
Inner block, start. x (0x7ffd6e6b8abc) = 42
Inner block, end.   x (0x7ffd6e6b8ab8) = 123
Outside, end.       x (0x7ffd6e6b8abc) = 42
```

[[Live demo](https://tio.run/##jY/BDoIwEETv/YoNBkMNEkVvqHdP/oAXbKs04pa0xZAYvr0WMIaDMextZ2dfZtjyxphzM4msrLmAnbFcqqQ4ECLRwiOXGD2V5BReBPx0YgN72KZZv1faK9coONXWSC5iMDbXNulO3heFFfXmkJ8xiKEHwYLOmxgaOvwP1DHpiCg0XErF7l/aFNI43TrdZP/BAnkyMWL7u@iHMLWoFrbWCKuMtMS5Nw)]

This program outputs the memory address and value of `x`. Most uses of `x` refer to the outer variable declared at the beginning of main. But within the inner block, after `int x = 123;`, all occurrences of `x` refer to a second, separate variable that happens to also be called `x` (but is otherwise independent).

When execution leaves the inner block, the outer `x` variable becomes visible again.

This is also referred to as [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

In your code, the outer `len` is never modified, so `while(len > 1)` is always true.

---

By the way, shadowing is a very common concept in most languages that support block scoping:

- [Perl](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@0OFWhuKQoM7nEmgvELk8sysvMSy@25uLKrVRQqVCwVTAxsuYqKMrMK1FQ8i8tKc5MSdUBakksKtFTAIEKBQ0lHYUYlQodBSVNoHKVipg8JWuuai6QJFSfZ15eapFCUk5@cjZcLw59IF0wmw2NjK1xGpOal6KH2/paDCdD1eN28v//AA)
- [JavaScript](https://tio.run/##dZBBT8MwDIXv/RXWOASkrRGD0yp@AFyQKIjjlCaPrZDGVeJN1RC/vbSwIXqYj/bz8/f8bvYm2Vi3sgjs0Pdql0BJYm1FFVnmIdTRHd0ui8xySOyRe95czh53kmqH@aA1UXIaaxTO5tRdFdlnNja0JtUpsiYooQo0eDvaImJ1Gm9F2rTS2mEPzy1i3vCh9t7kHDcaYfFSasc26VdU@mGALX9g9RPeBptgoUsxggZBkh5gL57RtByNXzsYtz5wwPHUhP4@BESqPNuPvwT/6MeNU/Lr5c1v47wBgsun8b/OPOuonD6r778B)
- [Haskell](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM0/BykrB019BQ5MLzLNVSMnnUgCCnNQShQog18QIzC0oLQkuKfLJU9BQ8i8tKc5MSdVRKC5JLCrRA8mCVSopaGsrFGfklytUaIL1QE1C0@6Zl5dapJCUk5@cDTcCq3ZkVxgaGRM0KzUvRQ@XU7A5H6oem/P//wcA)
- [Common Lisp](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jJ7VEQUOjQsHESFOTS0FBIy2/KDexRKFEQcm/tKQ4MyVVR6G4JLGoRE8BBCoUbBXqEutUlRQqwKphug2NjMHaUQzwzMtLLVJIyslPzoboRjMAl32peSl62JT//w8A)

Comment: Omg, Ofcourse! That was very obvious... Programming at 3AM is not a good idea it seems :) 
But quick question: what variable should the loop evaluate then? Because when I tried the same code in TIO it worked like I intended it originally?
Is it undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Your second `int len` creates a second, parallel, variable that goes away at the end of the {} block. The original `len` then returns to life, completely unchanged.  Without the second `int` the original variable is changed. With it the original `len` is effectively an unchanged constant and infinite loop.

Comment: "returns to life" isn't accurate.  It never died.  It just was obscured and then became visible again.

Comment: Well, yes, but I was not getting to technical for that guy.